# Set Timeout not working in React Native - Debug JS Remotely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I drove myself nuts trying to figure out what the problem is with my code. I am building a React Native application and developing in the IOS Simulator after running run-ios. I enabled Debug JS Remotely so I can verify the condition of my tokens returned from the server.

I am attempting to build a simple service that will refresh my tokens using a setTimeout.

```
let sessionTimeout = null;

export const session = (response) => {
  let tokens = response.tokens;
  Store.set(tokens);
  setSessionTimeout(tokens.access.expiresIn);
};

const setSessionTimeout = (duration) => {
  let time = duration - 5000;
  clearTimeout(sessionTimeout);

  sessionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('settimeout called');
    refreshToken();
  }, 1000);
};

const refreshToken = () => {
  let tokens = Store.get();

  refresh(tokens)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

In the above code a began my initial test by hardcoding 1000 and it worked fine. It successfully made the call to my server. I then attempted to implement the proper time duration and found it does not work. Even by replacing the 1000 with 2000 causes it to fail and the call to the backend is never made.

I then tried using the following packages and got the same result:

**react-native-timer**

**react-timer-mixin**

After banging my head on the wall for two days and having another attempt on stack shot down because my issue could not be reproduced I disabled the Debug JS Remotely and everything works as expected.

However now I am wondering how I am supposed to debug the frontend portion of my application with out the use of this feature. If anyone has any ideas or advice on issues like this I would appreciate the feedback as this is my first React Native app.

Comment: I've noticed issues with longer timeouts when in debug mode. Try a short timeout when in debug mode or try your actual timeout in non-debug mode.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it in non-debug mode as you suggested. And observed the behavior monitoring the backend.